# Office 365 Excel > Sort > "My data has headers" grayed out

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Using Excel from Office 365.

I've selected a range of cells from Row 1 down to Row 200. The cells have a header row, but when I try to sort the data `My data has headers` is grayed out and can not be selected.

If I select from Row 2 down to Row 200, and try to sort by a column, Row 1 is sorted as well, even though it was not selected in the data to be sorted.

Help appreciated.

Comment: please post some screenshots, it's difficult to understand your issue without it.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this occur when you have Filters turned on.  If you turn off the Data Filters, the "My data has headers" option should be available.

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen this happen when you are trying to sort columns but the Sort orientation is set to "Left to Right". In Custom Sort dialog box, click on Options button and correct the orientation to "Top to Bottom".

Comment: With all due respect, this strikes me as something that is theoretically true but irrelevant in reality. When would the sort orientation ever be set to “left to right” unless the user had just now selected that? It doesn’t seem to be a persistent (sticky) setting.

Comment: Isn’t it possible that a change was made to the Normal template by accident?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quick sort A-Z, instead select sort as such: and select bullet "Continue with the current selection" to NOT include anything that is not selected.
[image]